# Enable User Acces Management in Amazon AWS for Webapp based on Spring Security

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-security, amazon-cognito

We have an enterprise web application implemented based on **Spring-Security** for authentication/authorization. This application is currently deployed on-premises on client side and usually we connect it to existing AD/LDAP systems.

Now we'd like to setup this web application within **Amazon AWS** for demo purposes. Therefore we need a kind of an **user access frontend**, where users can register and as soon as an admin approved this, the user should have access to the webapp ui. In addition a simple analytics layer is needed, to see some information about the user access.

It is important to have this "frontend" (could be a simple website based on a CMS like WordPress) just to explain the demo, to have the user registration functionality and the analytics layer. We explicitly don't want to include this in the existing web application, so it must be decoupled from each other.

What could be the right approach to setup such an environment? I just need the right direction to dig into the topics.

After a first research, we see that **Amazon Cognito** could be the right backend service for user data management. But we don't see "an easy way" to enable a simple frontend as described above (e.g. I didn't find a wordpress plugin to connect wordpress user data management with Apache Cognito). Also on the backend side I haven't find useful information how to integrate Apache Cognito with Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple frontend we launched a [new feature](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=4673) which gives you basic signup/login pages for your user pool.